# Pass action method to inline block on CMS page in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages, third-party-module

I'm trying to **convert**

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="ibanners/view" name="ibanners.home" as="home">
    <action method="setGroupCode"><code>home</code></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Into an **inline block** to use inside the CMS home page, I've got

```
{{block type="ibanners/view" name="ibanners.home" as="home.banner" setGroupCode="home" template="ibanners/default.phtml"}}
```

But it's not doing anything, can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{block type="ibanners/view" name="ibanners.home" as="home.banner" group_code="home" template="ibanners/default.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Still doesn't load anything :-(

Comment: have you added `ibanners/view` block to whitelist?

Comment: Ah - That's helped - the template is loading - it's still not setting the setGroupCode

Comment: May I know how are you using groupcode in your template?